# Unable to change the date format for as.Date to be able to read the date when importing using read.csv()

Tags: r, date

When I export to excel using write.csv(XYZ) the date format in the entire column changes to:

```
01 01 2016
```

There are **GAPS** in the Month, Day and Year

Next, when I import the data using "read.csv" and use:

as.Date(XYZ$date), the date format does not change.

If i try to perform any operation on the date column the output is:

> Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) :    character string is not in a
>   standard unambiguous format

Please help me resolve this. I have also tried to change the Format of the date in Excel, however it doesn't seem to recognize the exported format from R.

Comment: When you say the format "changes", are you referring to how things appear in Excel? Have you looked at the text file itself (with a text editor)? Excel often reformats cells on import, for which the control is in Excel, not R.

Comment: Read about [R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Edit your post with output of `str(XYZ)`, `dput(XYZ)`.

Comment: Yes @rosscova have checked in excel. It seems there is some sort of permanent change to the format in excel and any formatting that i apply except for / and - will work. Basically the goal is to change the date in the d//m/yy or d-m-y so that as.Date can recognise it and I can do the operations.

Comment: See the answer I've posted below. Does that help?

Comment: Excel changes the format in a weird and to me, alien way. I don't see how we can reproduce this without Excel.

Comment: Thank You @RomanLuštrik I have found a way around this.          1. Change the excel file to "xlsx" format & change the dates format to dd/mm/yy using the "right click and format in excel" 2. Install the "xlsx" package in R 3. Import the xlsx file using the read.xlsx() function  4. use the as.Date() function for the dates columns. Now it should interpret the dates perfectly

Comment: Feel free to post this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that importing to Excel then exporting again to get back into R is changing the format of your dates, try applying something like this after importing back to `R`:

```
as.Date( XYZ$date, format = "%d %m %Y" )
```

This specifies R's `as.Date` function the format of the dates to be converted.

NOTE: preferably avoid this problem by either a) telling Excel not to convert your date values, or b) avoiding Excel entirely :)

Comment: I tried every permutation & combination of this: as.Date( XYZ$date, format = "%d %m %Y" ) Unfortunately it doesnt work. I asked around at work, the other analysts also faced this. But yes your recommendation to not export to excel is helpful. Thank You. As I'm new to R, i'm curious to know if you have used the RExcel Add In in Excel or the Excel packages in R? I'm considering working with excel as well. Or if you have any suggestions along how I can use R & Excel without importing/exporting each time

Comment: As far as you've described, this should work. In what way is it not working? You could provide a sample of your data (use `dput`) so we can get a better look at it.